# Selected column won't display in grid

Tags: acumatica

I have a processing screen based on a PXProjection of SOShipment.  I want to carry the selected column from SOShipment through to the grid for individual row processing.  No matter what I do, I cannot get it to display.  In the form design, Selected shows as an invisible field.  Also, another weird thing is that if I click the column configuration in the top left corner of the grid, Selected does not show.  If I click return to default and move it to the top, then the Selected column appears on the grid.  A page reload though causes it to disappear.  See my projection definition below:

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using System;
namespace EDIASNs
{

[Serializable]
[PXProjection(typeof(Select2<SOShipment,
    LeftJoin<SOOrderShipment, On<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.shipmentNbr>>,
    LeftJoin<SOOrder, On<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<SOOrderShipment.orderNbr>>>>>),
    Persistent = true)]

public partial class EDASNShipProj : SOShipment
{
    #region OrderNbr
    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, BqlField = typeof(SOOrder.orderNbr), IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Nbr")]
    public virtual string OrderNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class orderNbr : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region OrderCustomerRefNbr
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(SOOrder.customerRefNbr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Document Id")]
    public virtual String OrderCustomerRefNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class orderCustomerRefNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region OrderCustomerOrderNbr
    [PXDBString(40, IsUnicode = true, BqlField = typeof(SOOrder.customerOrderNbr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Customer Order")]
    public virtual String OrderCustomerOrderNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class orderCustomerOrderNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrTruckNbr
    [PXDBInt(BqlField = typeof(SOShipmentExt.usrTruckNbr))]
    [PXDefault(0, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Truck Nbr")]
    public virtual int? UsrTruckNbr { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTruckNbr : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the select from the graph:

```
    public class EDASNCreateProcess : PXGraph<EDASNCreateProcess>
{
    public PXCancel<EDCreateASNFilter> Cancel;
    public PXFilter<EDCreateASNFilter> Filter;

    [PXFilterable]
    public PXFilteredProcessing<EDASNShipProj, EDCreateASNFilter,
        Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<Where2<
                Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.customerID>, IsNull, 
                    Or<EDASNShipProj.customerID, Equal<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.customerID>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.startDate>, IsNull, 
                    Or<SOShipment.shipDate, GreaterEqual<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.startDate>>>>>>,
            And<Where<SOShipment.shipDate, LessEqual<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.endDate>>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.shipVia>, IsNull, 
                    Or<SOShipment.shipVia, Equal<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.shipVia>>>>>>,
            And<Where<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.truckNbr>, IsNull, 
                    Or<SOShipmentExt.usrTruckNbr, Equal<Current<EDCreateASNFilter.truckNbr>>>>>>,
            And<Where<SOShipment.status, Equal<SOShipmentStatus.open>>>>,
            And<Where<SOShipmentExt.usrEDIStatus, Equal<SOShipmentEDIStatus.truckAssigned>, 
                    Or<SOShipmentExt.usrEDIStatus, Equal<SOShipmentEDIStatus.newStat>>>>>,
            And<Where<EDASNShipProj.orderCustomerRefNbr, IsNotNull>>>,
        OrderBy<Asc<SOShipment.customerID, 
                Asc<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerId, 
                Asc<SOOrderExt.usrEDICustomerVendorId, 
                Asc<SOShipment.shipVia,
                Asc<SOShipmentExt.usrTruckNbr, 
                Asc<SOShipment.customerLocationID>>>>>>>> Shipment;
```

The datamember for the grid is Shipment.

I also tried creating a new Selected attribute on the projection and setting it as an override with no success.  How can I get the Selected column to come through from SOShipment?

Comment: Just bumping this question.  I have not been able to resolve this issue.

Comment: how you declared that column on aspx page?

Comment: I used the standard method to add a field.  <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" TextAlign="Center" Type="CheckBox" Width="60px">
                    </px:PXGridColumn>

Comment: Could you please also add definition of SOOrderExt and SOShipmentExt? One more question, why EDASNShipProj is declared as partial? What else it has in other files?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but I have abandoned this approach and went with a virtual DAC inside the graph which allows me to populate it with data from several joined tables to provide all the required date for my list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Project DAC declaration is wrong. `public partial class EDASNShipProj : SOShipment`. Projection DAC is declared as inherited from SOShipment

It should be like this and also for selected field, you need to add it projection DAC. please find the screenshot for reference.  `public class EDASNShipProj : IBqlTable`

[image]